# First install on a laptop without internet access

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, grub2, system-installation

I'm a first time Linux installer

I've been using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/583886/574741) that is for a slightly different version of my laptop and most of it has worked (it should be noted that I am completely replacing the operating system and not dual booting).

The two problems I currently have are that I don't have an internet connection (which is expected as per the guide in the answer) and when I'm installing it says that grub installation has failed. it allows me to go past this but the installer crashes immediately after.

My attempted fix for this was using `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` however this hits an error `Failed to get canonical path of /cow`.

I can't think of a way to gain internet access on the laptop as it has no ethernet ports.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the Asus X205TA or F205TA. It's essential to install with internet access and use 16.04 or later, 64-bit. GRUB will most likely install correctly if you do that - you do not need to follow that old guide. Please be aware there are still no audio drivers for this device.

**To answer your question directly**:

To get online, you can tether to a phone (for example Android) or tablet that has that feature and is connected to wifi. This works reliably.  Or, you can use a USB wifi adapter, but there is no guarantee that a particular model will work...

You must have an internet connection for any of the following to work.

Try the installation again. ("Erase the disk and install Ubuntu") For me GRUB installed perfectly both times I tried it with 16.04 with no special intervention.

For thorough installation guides for this device, see [How to install (L)Ubuntu 16.04 on the ASUS X205TA (F205TA)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869453/how-to-install-lubuntu-16-04-on-the-asus-x205ta-f205ta)